# make specific value selected in dropdown fields cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

In select drop down, make one particular value selected from values that are coming in drop down list Cakephp3.0. i am using below code:

```
    $abc = 'india';
    echo $this->Form->input('location_id', 
['empty' =>'Please select', 'required'=>'required', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label'=>false]);
```

Name of countries are coming in drop down list, but i want to make specific value selected which is set as variable $abc (i.e india).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. Your question is difficult to read

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

**use the 'default' key in**

```
 $abc = array('1' => 'One','2'=> 'Two');
 echo  $this->Form->input('location_id',
                          'options' => $abc, 
                          default' =>$abc[1], 
                          ['empty' =>'Please select',
                          'required'=>'required', 
                          'class' => 'form-control',
                          'label'=>false]
                         );
```

**where $abc[0] is the key of the item you want as selected**

**like this :**

```
$options = array('M' => 'Male', 'F' => 'Female');
echo $this->Form->select('field', $options, array('default' => 'F'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **value** option of [form input helper](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-inputs). Like this :

```
$selected = 'india';
echo $this->Form->input('location_id', ['empty' =>'Please select', 'required'=>'required', 'class' => 'form-control', 'label'=>false, 'value'=> $selected]);
```

Suggestion - Read the docs once and then start the development. You will never get stuck at such simple problems. And refer docs first whenever you get stuck at anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  $form->input('field_name', array(
            'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $arrayOfOptions, // typically set from $this->find('list') in controller 
    'label'=> 'Label name here',
    'value' => $arrProjectLeaderDetails['id'],  // specify default value 
    'escape' => false,  // prevent HTML being automatically escaped
    'error' => false,
    'class' => 'input_select_medium'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

In cakephp4 :

```
echo $this->Form->select(
'field_name', [1,2,3,4,5,6],
['empty', => '(Click to select Something']
);
```

Scroll down a bit from here in the docs:  https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls